# How do I complile specific java classes into a jar with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, javac, swagger-codegen

Inside an existing project I am using a shell script to pull swagger from a certain location. I am then using swagger-codegen to generate pojos from the swagger.  I want to compile these pojos into a JAR (with dependencies). This new JAR then needs to be added as a dependency to the project so the pojos can be used.

All of this is happening from the build.gradle file.

The code path in the build.gradle should look something like this:

1. Run the shell script to grab the swagger json file.
2. Grab the swagger-codegen jar
3. Generating the pojos using the swagger-codegen jar and json file
4. Create JAR file from the pojos with dependencies
5. Include the JAR file as a dependency in the project

I am having trouble with step 4.  When I try to run javac manually I get the package does not exist errors because it can not locate the dependencies.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't keep a copy of the Swagger file in the project? I ask because there is a plugin that will take care of all of the above if you can keep a local copy of the Swagger and update the file as needed.

Comment: The swagger comes from a third-party source. The shell script basically runs a wget.

Comment: Do you _need_ to download it with the shell script every time?